# how much over head is added to the netwok time by htons

Tags: c++, network-programming

I want to measure time for sending and getting back response over TCP, and I'd want to know how much time take the conversion from little-endian to big-endian by `htons` function.

Comment: None for all practical purposes.

Comment: @Shawn Not none, but infinitesimal ;)

Comment: @nada try and read the following words from Shawn's comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On ordinary hardware of our technology era:

- Sending and receiving data over TCP is a process operating in the timescale of a few milliseconds to a few minutes.
- Converting endianness of a few bytes in memory is a process operating in the timescale of a few nanoseconds.

> I'd want to know how much time take the conversion from little-endian to big-endian by htons function

**Negligible, by 6 orders of magnitude.**

Answer (score 1):

You can use high_resolution_clock to measure the time before and after the function call then you can calculate the duration.

```
#include <chrono>

high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

functionToMeasure();

high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

auto duration = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
```

Comment: first of all tnx for the answer but I don't think it will work because from what I understand the call - '    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT); ' it's not where the conversion happened but sort of "bind" the socket to the conversion, but I will be happy to be proved wrong and learn something new

Comment: @yaodav: `htons` does immediately the conversion.

Comment: @yaodav You can actually see that conversion in the assembly code of the benchmark Jarod42 shared.